# Solving matrix whose distance from 2 other matrix is known

Tags: math

How would I solve for xa,xb,xc, and xd?

[0;1;4;9].-[xa;xb;xc;xd]=a vector which has elements that add up to -12

[0;1;8;27].-[xa;xb;xc;xd]=a vector which has elements that add up to 10

From what I can tell there is only one value for each x-element that satisfies both equations.

The ".-" notation is used in octave to mean element by element subtraction

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to do your math homework for you.

Comment: the question is used in a computer program

Answer (score 1):

Both equations with the summation condition are equivalent to

```
xa+xb+xc+xd == 26
```

and any combination of 4 numbers with this sum is a solution. There is no more information contained in your conditions.